# Hibernate: multiple selects @OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate

I have three entity:

```
Users(id, username, password...); BoughtItems(id, userid, itemcat, itemid); ItemCustomizations(id(id of item), slot(id of color), color)
```

When i fetch like this in BoughtItems.java:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "id")
@OrderBy("slot")
private List<ItemCustomization> customColors = new ArrayList<>();
```

Hibernate asks database for each item:

```
Hibernate: select customcolo0_.itemid as itemid1_2_0_, customcolo0_.itemid 
as itemid1_3_0_, customcolo0_.slot as slot2_3_0_, customcolo0_.itemid as 
itemid1_3_1_, customcolo0_.slot as slot2_3_1_, customcolo0_.color as 
color3_3_1_ from shop_customizations customcolo0_ where 
customcolo0_.itemid=? order by customcolo0_.slot
```

**My question**

How to proper optimize my mappings to reduce `mysql` server performance hit?

Can I somehow optimize query/item to 1 query?

Comment: I know one thing about OneToMany. When using OneToMany, JoinTable is way way way way better than JoinColumn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for batch size feature of hibernate. See [example](https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-tuning-queries-using) here.

Batch size defines how many collections should be loaded. For example if you have 10 `BoughtItems` in session with batch size =5 , only two sql queries will be fired to fetch `customColors` collections for all possible `BoughtItems`

See [Possible fetching strategies](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-fetching-strategies-examples/) in hibernate